# IF Else Using Ruby Logic depending on Params sent in

Tags: ruby, if-statement

am sending in the parameters that are at the bottom of this posting but they are getting posted to Load instead of Hotload

Can you see what i am doing wrong here...

i am sending in a parameter of hotload so it should change the post_type to Hotload

```
class MajorPoster

  @queue = :major_posters_posting

  def self.perform(_post)
    post_clone = _post.clone
    post_type  = Load
    post_type  = Hotload if (_post[:hotload])
    post_type  = Truck if (_post[:available])
    begin
    result = post_type.send("post",_post)
    rescue => detail
      Resque.enqueue(SecondChance, { :queue => "major_posters_posting", :post => post_clone, :exception_class => detail.class.to_s, :exception_str => detail.to_s })
    else
      Notification.check(result.id, post_type)
      #TODO
    end
  end
end
```

log file of params being sent in...

```
{:equipment_id=>34, :comments=>"9145662 ~Load Max~", :user_id=>"10181", :origin=>"Cy Of Industry, CA", :dest=>"Loveland, CO", :pickup=>2014-07-08 12:00:00 -0500, :delivery=>2014-07-10 12:00:00 -0500, :rate=>"CALL", :length=>"53", :hotload=>"True"}
{:equipment_id=>34, :comments=>"9163608 ~Load Max~", :user_id=>"10181", :origin=>"Auburndale, FL", :dest=>"Paw Paw, MI", :pickup=>2014-07-06 12:00:00 -0500, :delivery=>2014-07-09 12:00:00 -0500, :rate=>"CALL", :length=>"53", :hotload=>"True"}
{:equipment_id=>34, :comments=>"9158096 ~Load Max~", :user_id=>"10181", :origin=>"Auburndale, FL", :dest=>"Paw Paw, MI", :pickup=>2014-07-03 12:00:00 -0500, :delivery=>2014-07-06 12:00:00 -0500, :rate=>"CALL", :length=>"53", :hotload=>"True"}
{:equipment_id=>34, :comments=>"9163315 ~Load Max~", :user_id=>"10181", :origin=>"Auburndale, FL", :dest=>"Paw Paw, MI", :pickup=>2014-07-03 12:00:00 -0500, :delivery=>2014-07-06 12:00:00 -0500, :rate=>"CALL", :length=>"53", :hotload=>"True"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The keys of the params you are sending are symbols, not strings - you should change the code accordingly:

```
def self.perform(_post)
  post_clone = _post.clone
  post_type  = Load
  post_type  = Hotload if (_post[:hotload])
  post_type  = Truck if (_post[:available])
  # ...
```

Comment: try printing `puts _post[:hotload]` inside the method